# Inserting and updating, deleting in DB

Tags: java, database, primary-key

I had a ticket request with me and i am not knowing how to handle. Let me explain the whole scenario in a clear manner.

In my database I have the primary key as `firstCode` which is six digit long ex: `PQRS11` and `shortCode` (which is not a primary) which is three digit length: `PQR`.

This `firstCode` I can create for various organizations, such as `PQRS11`, `PQRS12`, `PQRS13`... The `shortCode` I generated in using `substring(0,3)` which gives me `PQR`.

The problem is that in DB only one `PQR` should exist. If I select `PQRS11` and select a radio button to generate `shortCode` it should check in the DB and if any `PQR` exists
then it should delete that and update the same for `PQRS11`.

How to do this? I am in great confusion.

Comment: *"How to do this ?"*  Try doing something, *anything.*  If it fails, ask a specific question.

Comment: *try something* - but not with the production database, please :D

Comment: @Andreas_D  Yes, good caveat.  ;)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: i am using DB2. The code is something like organization.setshortCode(organiztion.getFirstCode().substring(0, 3));

Answer (score 0):

You should create another table that holds the firstcodes and a foreign key identifier to another table which holds the shortcodes and the foreign key linked to the firstcodes table. Check below for a reference example

```
           table1                                table2
      id | shortcode | firstcodeFK             id | firstcode | firstcodeFK 
       1 |  PQR      |   11                     1 |   PQRS11  |     11
       2 |  PQRS     |   12                     2 |   PQRS12  |     11
       3 |  PQER     |   13                     3 |   PQER    |     13
```

So now everytime you need to access all members of the PQR code, just search for the foreign key from table1 and join it to where it matches the key on table2 to get your results, then after you may update your radio button and carry out further instructions